# how to remove duplicate item from list view which is coming from server

Tags: android

i'm a little new to android.  This is my code below. I have used a list here, I'm fetching floor numbers but getting repeated values.

I have stored repeated values in server as json data

pls help me to remove duplicate items from list. thanks all

```
   final List<Customer> floors= new ArrayList<Customer>();
   jsonResponse = "";
   for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
      JSONObject customer = (JSONObject) response.get(i);
      String email = customer.getString("email");
      String name = customer.getString("f_name");
      Double balance = customer.getDouble("balance");
      String phone = customer.getString("phone");
      String streetName = customer.getString("street");
      String wardName = customer.getString("ward");
      String doorNumber = customer.getString("door");
      String floorNumber = customer.getString("floor");
      String houseType=customer.getString("type");
      floors.add(new Customer(email, name, balance, doorNumber, phone, 
             streetName, houseType,wardName,floorNumber));
   }
```

From below here I'm fetching floor name....

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
  LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
  View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_floor, parent, false);
  TextView tv = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.txtResponse2);
  tv.setText(floors.get(position).getFloor());
  return rootView;
}
```

Comment: Which field is each floor identified by? email?

Answer (score 0):

For instance, if you want to remove duplicate on email field, you coud use HashMap. Use email as key of HashMap and before inserting customer, test if email exists, as this:

```
final Map<String, Customer> floorsMap= new HashMap<String,Customer>();
   jsonResponse = "";
   for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
      JSONObject customer = (JSONObject) response.get(i);
      String email = customer.getString("email");
      String name = customer.getString("f_name");
      Double balance = customer.getDouble("balance");
      String phone = customer.getString("phone");
      String streetName = customer.getString("street");
      String wardName = customer.getString("ward");
      String doorNumber = customer.getString("door");
      String floorNumber = customer.getString("floor");
      String houseType=customer.getString("type");

      if(!floorsMap.containsKey(email)){
          floorsMap.put(email, new Customer(email, name, balance, doorNumber, phone, streetName, houseType,wardName,floorNumber));
      }
   }
   final List<Customer> floors = new ArrayList<Customer>(floorsMap.values());
```

Comment: @kaushal, is it useful ?